# Preserve Bash Completion for all commands that are prepended by a custom command

Tags: bash, bash-completion

I have a script which allows to execute Bash processes in the background, i called it "backy". Programs I want to run in background I call like this:

```
backy long-running-script param1 param2
```

The problem is now that I loose the Bash completion for `long-running-script` if I prepend another script.

I want to write a Bash completion file which preserves not only the Bash completion for `long-running-script` and all of its parameters, also for every other script that I want to call with backy.

I have some experience with Bash completion, but I'm just missing the command which I can insert into my Bash completion script so that it completes with the completion of the script that is to be called. Any ideas?

My completion so far:

```
have backy &&
_backy_complete()
{
  local cur prev goals

  COMPREPLY=()
  cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}

  # How to get the completion from the script that is the param for backy, 
  # in a generic way?
  COMPREPLY=( ????? )
  return 0
} &&
complete -F _backy_complete backy
```

**EDIT - SOLUTION:**

Thanks to Lekensteyn, I replaced the content of my existing bash completion script with just this line:

```
complete -F _command backy
```

Comment: You do not have to add the solution to your question, since it appears straight in the answer under the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is already a bash_completion function for such cases:

```
complete -F _command backy
```

It's used for autocompleting the commands after `sudo`, `fakeroot` and others. Any arguments passed to backy are ignored like:

```
backy --whatever --this --is=ignored not ignored anymore
```